# How does this if statement read?

Tags: php

How does this if statement read out loud?

```
if (!$_SESSION['stuff']) { 
    $age=12;
}
```

(Admin, please change the non-descript title since I don't know what to call the boolean expression in the if statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If not `stuff` in `$_SESSION`

If the value (or lack thereof) at index `stuff` of Array `$_SESSION` evaluates to `false`, then set `$age` to INT value `12`.

Comment: Oh okay, so isn't "!" behaving the same way as this the same as "!isset" would?

Comment: @LedZeppelin Effectively. `!` is NOT. `!isset()` is "not isset()", as `!$var` is "not (the value of $var)". Not being set would yield "not NULL" == "not false" == "true".

Comment: In the context if your question, no, they're not exactly the same. '!' does mean "not" in both, but '!$var' is not the same as '!isset($var)'. One is checking if the value (or lack thereof) evaluates to false, the other is checking if the value is not set at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the exclamation mark? That is a "not".

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the "stuff" session, set "age" to 12.

Comment: What is "it"? This sounds like you're choosing among various sessions, which is not the case. It's evaluating the value of a session variable named "stuff".